# Restringir contenido según role

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ms-access, function

Tengo este código que hace lo siguiente:
Permite crear un shortcode en Wordpress donde solo permite que X role pueda ver el contenido dentro de este.

```
    function estec_check_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'wcfm_vendor' || 'school' || 'estec', $user->roles ) && !is_null($content) && !is_feed()) {
        return do_shortcode($content);
    }
    return '<p></p>';
}
add_shortcode('estec', 'estec_check_shortcode');
```

El problema es que cualquier role al ingresar puede ver el contenido (Excepto aquellos que no se encuentran logeados).
En cambio si lo escribo de la siguiente manera, aquellos que tienen el role de wcfm_vendor son capases de ver el contenido, el resto de los roles no pueden ver el contenido dentro del shortcode.

```
 function school_check_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'wcfm_vendor', $user->roles ) && !is_null($content) && !is_feed()) {
        return do_shortcode($content);
    }
    return '<p></p>';
}
add_shortcode('school', 'school_check_shortcode');
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que todos aquellos usuarios que sean wcfm_vendor, school y estec, puedan ver el contenido dentro del shortcode.